# save result to database from autocomplete javascript

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I have this code to get results selected by the user and send it to a mysql database. Is there a better way of doing this than using `switch` and putting in every case manually like this?

My current code:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
  //alert(ui);
  var selectedCase = false;
  var selectedItem = '';

  var item = ui.item;
  switch (item.type) {
    case 'brands':
      selectedCase = true;
      selectedItem = base_url + 'brand/' + item.BrandUniqueName;
      window.location.href = base_url + 'brand/' + item.BrandUniqueName;

      break;
    case 'categories':
      selectedCase = true;
      selectedItem = base_url + 'categories/' + item.CategoryUniquename;
      window.location.href =
        base_url + 'categories/' + item.CategoryUniquename;

      break;
    case "categoryBrand":
      selectedCase = true;
      selectedItem = base_url + 'brand/' + item.BrandUniqueName + '? 
      category = '+item.CategoryUniquename;
      window.location.href = base_url + 'brand/' + item.BrandUniqueName + '? 
      category = '+item.CategoryUniquename;

      break;
    case 'offercategory':
      selectedCase = true;
      selectedItem = base_url + 'offercategory/' + item.OfferCategory;
      window.location.href =
        base_url + 'offercategory/' + item.OfferCategory;

      break;
    case 'vendorOfferCategory':
      selectedCase = true;
      selectedItem = base_url + 'offers/' + item.UniqueName + '? 
      category = '+item.OfferCategory;
      window.location.href = base_url + 'offers/' + item.UniqueName + '? 
      category = '+item.OfferCategory;

      break;
    case 'vendor':
      selectedCase = true;
      selectedItem = base_url + 'offers/' + item.VendorUniqueName;
      window.location.href = base_url + 'offers/' + item.VendorUniqueName;

      break;
    case 'offers':
      selectedCase = true;
      selectedItem = base_url + 'offers/' + item.UniqueName;
      window.location.href = base_url + 'offers/' + item.UniqueName;

      break;
    case 'vendorcategory':
      selectedCase = true;
      selectedItem = base_url + 'topcategories/' + item.UniqueName;
      window.location.href = base_url + 'topcategories/' + item.UniqueName;

      break;
    case 'vendors':
      selectedCase = true;
      selectedItem = base_url + 'offers/' + item.UniqueName;
      window.location.href = base_url + 'offers/' + item.UniqueName;

      break;
    case 'products':
      selectedCase = true;
      selectedItem = base_url + 'products/' + item.InternalLink;
      window.location.href = base_url + 'products/' + item.InternalLink;

      break;
    case "Not Available":
      //$("#autocomplete").val('');
      break;

  }
  if (selectedCase == true) {
    // alert(selectedItem);
    var rslt = selectedItem;
    this.saveResult();
  }
  //$("#project-id").val(ui.item.email);                    
  return false;
},
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I did n't understood your question

Comment: right now i have to take the results from  every case,i want to do it single time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can use a hashmap like that ,

```
 var map = {brands: 
              {
              url:'brand/',
              attribute:'InternalLink'
              },
          categoryBrand: 
              {
               url:'brand/',
               attribute:'InternalLink',
               extraPar: '?category=',
               extraAttr: 'CategoryUniquename'
              }
         };
```

and use them like this :

```
selectedCase = true;
  selectedItem = base_url + map[item.type]['url'] 
                 + item[map[item.type]['attribute']] 
                 + (map[item.type]['extraPar'] ? (map[item.type]['extraPar']+item[map[item.type]['extraAttr']]) : '');
  window.location.href = base_url + map[item.type]['url'] 
                 + item[map[item.type]['attribute']] 
                 + (map[item.type]['extraPar'] ? (map[item.type]['extraPar']+item[map[item.type]['extraAttr']]) : '');
```

and for the case the type isn't in your cases you can just check before you 
 access

```
if(map[item.type]){
 // do what you want
} else {
 // type is not defined
}
```

Comment: will try it today,any idea on storing the results?

Comment: @DhirajChetry you can use localStorage or do an AJAX Request if you want to save it in a database ,